# Addeventlistener converted to IE. Maybe another error?

Tags: javascript

i've made a simple script which will reveal a div (inside another) when hovered on the outer div (does this make sence?)

anyway this is the code.

```
for (var ost = 1; ost <= 16; ost++) {
        var maelk = String("sovs"+ ost);
        document.getElementById(maelk).addEventListener('mouseover', on, false);
        document.getElementById(maelk).addEventListener('mouseout', off, false);
        }

    function on(e) {
        var t=e.currentTarget.id;
        var g= t.substr(4,5);
        var v="celltext" + g;
        $("#"+v).show();
            //stop(true, false).fadeIn("slow");
    }

    function off(e) {
        var t=e.currentTarget.id;
        var g= t.substr(4,5);
        var v="celltext" + g;

        $("#"+v).hide();
            //stop(true, true).fadeOut("slow");

    }
```

But this doesn't work on Internet Explorer. I heard the reason was addEventListener. So i tried editing the code to this:

```
for (var ost = 1; ost <= 16; ost++) {
        var maelk = String("sovs"+ ost);
        var maelkelement = document.getElementById(maelk);

    if (!maelkelement.addEventListener) {
        maelkelement.attachEvent('mouseover', on, false);
        maelkelement.attachEvent('mouseout', off, false);
    }
    else {
        maelkelement.addEventListener('mouseover', on, false);
        maelkelement.addEventListener('mouseout', off, false);
    }

    function on(e) {
        var t=e.currentTarget.id;
        var g= t.substr(4,5);
        var v="celltext" + g;
        $("#"+v).show();
            //stop(true, false).fadeIn("slow");
    }

    function off(e) {
        var t=e.currentTarget.id;
        var g= t.substr(4,5);
        var v="celltext" + g;

        $("#"+v).hide();
            //stop(true, true).fadeOut("slow");

    }
```

The only difference is the IF sentence to communicate with IE. This doesn't work though.

Anybody got any ideas?

Help is much appreciated, and thank you in advance

Regards,
Mathias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event names are slightly different when you use `attachEvent`. You'll need to use `'onmouseover'` and `'onmouseout'` instead:

```
if (!maelkelement.addEventListener) {
    maelkelement.attachEvent('onmouseover', on);
    maelkelement.attachEvent('onmouseout', off);
}
```

See also:

- MDN: [`element.AddEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener#Compatibility) (section "Legacy Internet Explorer and attachEvent")
- [MSDN: attachEvent method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [MSDN: List of events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: loose the third parameter: IE doesn't support event capturing, so that false is useless. If anything it might trigger errors

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Additional parameters are likely going to be ignored. But thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if this worked on the first element, as the functions on & off have not been defined before they are refereed to.
I would change to

```
var on = function(e) {...}
var off = function(e) {...}
for(...) {
  ....addEventListener(..., on, false);
  ....addEventListener(..., off, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zeta is right: use `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`, but that still won't fix your problem. In addition to that, it's important to note that IE doesn't pass the event object to the handler by default. Instead IE only has a single -global- event object, so both your `on` and `off` functions must start like so:

```
function onOrOff(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;//get the global event for ie
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;//IE's bubbling model doesn't have a target, but a source element
    //Now you can finally get some work done
    if (e.preventDefault)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return;
    }
    e.returnValue = false;
    e.cancelBubble = true;//bubbling || propagation and preventDefault works differently, too
}
```

Lastly: again, thanks to the bubbling model IE doesn't support event capturing. The `attachEvent` method therefore doesn't have a third parameter, so loose the false in the IE branch and you should be all set